# Custom model binder for Dynamic Web API Layer

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'd like to write a custom model binding that trims strings if they have a `[TrimString]` attribute in .NET Core 2. I've written this ModelBinding for MVC 2, however I am using the Dynamic Web API to autogenerate the APIs.

Is it possible to add custom model bindings to the Dynamic Web API in ABP 3.1.2 in .NET Core?

Answer (score 1):

you can use interception. Interception works just before the real app service method execute. So you can traverse your input object and modify strings.
AuditingInterceptor can guide you how to write a interception.

See 
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/master/src/Abp/Auditing/AuditingInterceptor.cs#L55

and this
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/161

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to switch to ABPFramework, https://github.com/abpframework/abp.
Which you can use ApplicationService and it supports ASP.NET Core ModelBinder.